# Magento : change price in cart on the fly

Tags: magento, shopping-cart, cart, observers

We have 2 observers to change product price in the cart : `checkout_cart_product_add_after` to change price the first time the product is added to cart, and `checkout_cart_update_items_after` to change price for each item in the cart (when user click the "Modify cart" button on cart page). Both are running OK.

My question : On the cart page, when user clicks the link "Edit" to edit the product in product page (so he can change quantity, ...) and clicks the **"Update cart"** button, this update button does not read any observer to refresh price. Only the quantity is refreshed.

How to force this **"Update cart"** (*on product page*) action to process the code in observer? Is there another observer for this? The code in `checkout_cart_product_add_after` is executed just the first time the product is added to the cart?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Copy this file:

> app\code\core\Mage\Checkout\controllers\CartController.php

To:

> app\code\local\Mage\Checkout\controllers\CartController.php

Go to:

```
public function updateItemOptionsAction()
{
```

Add your custom logic or fire off a custom event you can listen to and run the same logic on.

Don't forget to flush ;)